# Is there a way to add a new column in Sharepoint list that copies data from another column in that list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I'm using Sharepoint Online.

I have a column in a list that is currently "Multiple lines of text".
If I try to use the SP UI and manually alter the Column Type to "Single Line of Text" I get "unsupportedFieldTypeError".

If I use Sharepoint Designer 2013, and access the list and try to click "Column Type" when I highlight this column, nothing happens.

I would really like to know if I can create a new column that is a "Single line of text" that just copies the value of this "Multiple lines of text" column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Single Line Text field and copy field value using PnP PowerShell below：

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://zheguo.sharepoint.com/"
$ListName = "JqueryList"
$SourceColumn = "MultiField" #Internal Name of the Fields
$DestinationColumn = "SingleField"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credential Get-Credential

#Get all items from List
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $Listname

#Copy Values from one column to another
ForEach ($Item in $ListItems)
{
    Set-PnPListItem -List $Listname -Identity $Item.Id -Values @{$DestinationColumn = $Item[$SourceColumn]}
}
```

Result:

[image]

Before using the PowerShell, please install PnP PowerShell here:

[pnp/PnP-PowerShell](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: Copy Values from One Column to Another using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/05/sharepoint-online-copy-values-from-one-column-to-another-using-powershell.html)

Comment: Hi thanks,  

I seem to have a problem with the last line of code (loop):  

Set-PnPListItem : Field DestinationColumn not present in list. At line:1 char:31 + ... $ListItems){Set-PnPListItem -List $Listname -Identity $Item.Id -Value ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (SharePointPnP.P...sts.SetListItem:SetListItem) [Set-PnPListItem], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FIELDNOTINLIST,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.SetListItem  
  
Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Per the error FIELDNOTINLIST, please make sure $SourceColumn and $DestinationColumn is valid in your side. Please refer the function doc here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps